Hex Dump Annotation
I want to document the fields of tcpdump hex output.     I envision the 12-15 lines of 8 hex words each with comments to the side  Certain hex words, or more likely, pairs, would be circled (square more likely)  with a line going to a short sentence off to the right side.
Are there any packages like this already?   If not, suggestions on how to create my own?
The data looks like this:
0x0000:  4510 00a0 147b 4000 4006 a25f c0a8 010e 
0x0010:  c0a8 010f 0016 d646 9150 6099 43be f728  
0x0020:  8018 01f5 377d 0000 0101 080a 6847 f94f  
0x0030:  98a4 fde4 dd7c 2a89 7ed3 aaff 3bb1 adf4  
0x0040:  4dfe f0bd 705e 8011 14da f831 005c d3f4  
0x0050:  1bff 5c3d 302d 1072 4cbf 3608 bc2e 252e  

And what I want is to somehow highlight "705e 8011" on line 4.   I don't want to use color due to lack of color printer.  I want a box around those two words and a line from the box to the right where I can put a short description.

you might need to give people more clues about your intended input and desired output. what does tcpdump output look like, and show (just mock up a picture) what output do you want


\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(82pt,1pt-6\baselineskip){\ttfamily\framebox(5em,12pt){}}
    \put(250pt,1pt-6\baselineskip){\framebox(10em,12pt){something about this}}
    \put(90pt,1pt-6\baselineskip){\line(1,0){200pt}}

\end{picture}
\begin{verbatim}
0x0000:  4510 00a0 147b 4000 4006 a25f c0a8 010e 
0x0010:  c0a8 010f 0016 d646 9150 6099 43be f728  
0x0020:  8018 01f5 377d 0000 0101 080a 6847 f94f  
0x0030:  98a4 fde4 dd7c 2a89 7ed3 aaff 3bb1 adf4  
0x0040:  4dfe f0bd 705e 8011 14da f831 005c d3f4  
0x0050:  1bff 5c3d 302d 1072 4cbf 3608 bc2e 252e  
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}


I'd be interested in something similar. This seems to be only half a solution, as this part ("I want a box around those two words and a line from the box to the right where I can put a short description.") is not covered. Also it seems very cumbersome  (and error-prone - what if the font changes?) to place such a box based on absolute coordinates. Is there some way to do this inline?

well it's tt font so not really font dependent every character is .5em acros and I used \baselineskip for the vertical so you could easily replace the 82pt by  +10em or whatever, a bos on the right is eaxily added to the same picture mode  I'll addsomething

I chose to do a picture mode answer, you could of course use fancire annotation swith tikz etc, or an online markup (listings "escapeinside" might be useful) but I leave that for other answers. @CherryDT

does this really need verbatim?

@cfr you could use obeylines, but it seems odd to me to use non verbatim and online markup as then you can't directly use the script output, I thought it more natural to use the output directly and overlay the annotations

I had come up with a fancyvrb/Verbatim solution with \fbox but that moved the columns over and I still didn't have an explaining text.   Your solution also leaves the data aligned.

@DavidCarlisle I was thinking of whether semiverbatim would work with tikzmark here.

@cfr yes sure something like that, but it would be a different answer, here I wanted to use picture mode and wanted to demonstrate having the anotations out of line with the data. But you could use tikz or could have inline marks such as tikzmark.

Funny, David's solution works at home but at work I get a ERROR A  was expected here.   That is if any of the 3 commands in the picture environment are present.   An empty picture block doesn't generate an error.    The system at work is a generic RH 7 linux system with a 2013 version of LaTeX.    It is behind firewall and I can't update it.

do you have a really old latex ie a banner date older than 2020? try adding \usepackage{picture}  for a package offering a similar syntax in old latex.  see the latex change log: 2020-08-15  David Carlisle  David.Carlisle@latex-project.org

ltpictur.dtx, ltboxes.dtx:
Allow eTeX length expressions in picture coordinates.  @user1625344


With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix and TikZ to draw the frame and the label by using the PGF/TikZ nodes created by nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\ttfamily \small
\begin{NiceTabular}[light-syntax]{*{9}{c}}
0x0000: 4510 00a0 147b 4000 4006 a25f c0a8 010e ;
0x0010: c0a8 010f 0016 d646 9150 6099 43be f728 ;
0x0020: 8018 01f5 377d 0000 0101 080a 6847 f94f ;
0x0030: 98a4 fde4 dd7c 2a89 7ed3 aaff 3bb1 adf4 ;
0x0040: 4dfe f0bd 705e 8011 14da f831 005c d3f4 ;
0x0050: 1bff 5c3d 302d 1072 4cbf 3608 bc2e 252e ;
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (5-|4) rectangle (6-|5) 
        -- (6-|last) 
        node [draw,right] {something about this}
        ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}

As usual with nicematrix, you need several compilations.

